# How can I insert a new line for my typewriter effect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have put together a basic typewriter effect with React Hooks and Typescript.

```
const TypingText: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  const [subIndex, setSubIndex] = useState(0);

  const text = ["Line 1", "Line 2.", "Line 3.", "Line 4"]

  useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      setSubIndex((prev) => prev + 1);
    }, 100);

    if (subIndex === text[index].length) {
      setSubIndex(0);
      setIndex((prev) => prev + 1)
    }

    return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
  }, [subIndex]);

  const renderText = () => {
    let htmlArray: JSX.Element[] = [];

    if (subIndex === text[index].length) {
      htmlArray.push(<br />)
    } else {
      htmlArray.push(<p>{text[index].substring(0, subIndex)}</p>)
    }

    return htmlArray
  };

  return (
    <h1>
      {renderText()}
    </h1>
  )
};
```

This works well for 1 continuous block of text, but I cannot get it to insert a new line when the current array item has finished.

Can someone please advise me on what I should do.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would be very tempted to just create a new text array each time, which has all the content so far revealed. This should be easy to do with a for loop.

Then just render this (partial) text array structure using a conventional [react map approach](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#rendering-multiple-components).

[This CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-spence-sikqp?file=/src/App.js) demonstrates the approach.

Comment: Hi,
I'm not completely sure I follow.
The text is currently in an array and at the moment, I'm trying to loop through each character in a sentence, pushing it onto an array of `JSX.Eements` and inserting a `<br />` before each new sentence.
What do you mean by "create a new text array each time"?

Thanks

Comment: I put a codesandbox together to show. It seemed like you were facing unnecessary complexity from trying to actually construct a partial dom structure, when you needed to construct a partial data structure, and then just render that partial data structure with a conventional React approach. The codesandbox makes partial lines from the ORIGINAL_LINES depending how many characters have been 'revealed' so far.

Comment: Updated the sandbox to separate out the getPartialLines function.

Comment: Updated the sandbox to use a reducer to sum the chars in the lines.

Comment: Updated the sandbox to improve the quality of the getPartialLines function.